# R Text Mining: find correlations among words within a certain distance of a keyword

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus

I have been following this [example](https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html) and was wondering if it is possible to draw the figure 4.4 for combinations of words that were within 10 words of the keyword instead of words that are right next to each other.  For example, let's say I wanted to know which words were commonly within 10 words of "sir"?

Sorry, my company has disabled copying/pasting text on your website so I can't post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the 10 words difference. But one option may be to calculate co-occurrences on sentence-level, for example with the `udpipe::cooccurrence` function.